# How to add datapoints in animated line in Matlab gui through an event listener?

Tags: matlab, animation, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-gui

I am making a GUI app in Matlab using GUIDE. I have axes on which I am plotting some points on a push button click.
Now I want to use animated line to plot lines on same axes. The datapoints to add to animated line are coming from an event. So I need to add data points in an event listener.
I want to know how I can do that because that event listener does not have access to animated line.
Following is the code so far.

This function is called when push button is clicked-

```
function startButton_Callback(~, ~, handles)
    x = randi(100, 20);
    y = randi(100, 20);
    plot(x, y, 'o');
    la = newClass;
    addlistener(la,'statusAnnouncement',@StatusListener);
```

This is the function being called on event

```
function StatusListener(obj, eventData)
    h = animatedline;
    addpoints(h,eventData.coordinate(1),eventData.coordinate(2));
    drawnow
```

Points plotted using plot are being shown only. How do I show the animated line?
Also, I am not getting any error on command window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you can give the listener access to the `animtedline` object.

1. You can define `StatusListener` as a *subfunction* of `startButton_Callback`

   ```
   function startButton_Callback(~, ~, handles)

       h = animatedline;

       la = newClass;
       addlistener(la,'statusAnnouncement',@StatusListener);

       %// This as a subfunction so it can "see" h
       function StatusListener(src, evnt)
           h.addpoints(evnt.coordinate(1), evnt.coordinate(2));
       end
   end
   ```
2. Pass the `animtedline` object to the callback function via the anonymous function

   ```
   function startButton_Callback(~, ~, handles)
       h = animatedline;

       la = newClass;

       %// Use the callback but add h as an additional input argument
       addlistener(la, 'statusAnnouncement', @(s,e)StatusListener(s,e,h))
   end

   %// Note the additional input argument here
   function StatusListener(obj, evnt, h)
       h.addpoints(evnt.coordinate(1), evnt.coordinate(2))
   end
   ```
3. Update the `animatedline` *inside* of the anonymous function

   ```
   function startButton_Callback(~, ~, handles)
       h = animatedline;

       la = newClass;

       %// Don't define a separate function and just do the update here
       addlistener(la, 'statusAnnouncement', @(s,e)h.addpoints(e.coordinate(1), e.coordinate(2)))
   end
   ```
4. Store the `animatedline` object in the `guidata` of `appdata` of your figure.

   ```
   function startButton_Callback(~, ~, handles)

       h = animatedline;

       %// Store the handle within the appdata of the figure
       setappdata(gcbf, 'MyAnimatedLine', h)

       la = newClass;
       addlistener(la,'statusAnnouncement',@StatusListener);
   end

   function StatusListener(obj, evnt)
       %// Get the handle from the appdata of the figure
       h = getappdata(gcbf, 'MyAnimatedLine');
       h.addpoints(evnt.coordinate(1), evnt.coordinate(2))
   end
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my problem. I have a question though, In the 4th way, what is `gcbf` in `setappdata`. Is it accessible globally in all functions.

Comment: @PratikSinghal [`gcbf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcbf.html) is the handle to the figure containing the object whose callback was triggered. It is similar to using `gcf` but more robust. It is only valid when responding to a callback though.